# How to find a certain amount of same adjacent elements in a row of a nested list

Tags: python, list

There is a hotel e.g. of size 7x5. I need to create a function where

1. a number is given as parameter for finding the amount of **consecutive empty** rooms
2. returns the number of floor and room number in that.
   (depicted below: 0 is empty room and 1 is full)

[image]

e.g.:

1. if the parameter is 1, output will be
   "floor no: 5, start from room no: 1"
2. if the parameter is 2, output will be
   "floor no: 5, start from room no: 3"
3. if the parameter is 3, output will be
   "floor no: 5, start from room no: 3"
4. if the parameter is 4, output will be
   "floor no: 4, start from room no: 4"
5. if the parameter is 5, output will be
   "floor no: 2, start from room no: 1"
6. if the parameter is 6 (or 7), output will be
   "floor no: 1, start from room no: 1"
7. if the parameter is > 7, output will be
   "not possible to find in one floor"

preferably without using itertools.grupby.

My try:

```
def adjacent_rooms (amount):
    nested_list_temp = [[0]*7]*5
    nested_list = [list(i) for i in nested_list_temp]
    nested_list [1][5] = 1
    nested_list [2][3] = 1
    nested_list [2][4] = 1
    nested_list [3][2] = 1
    nested_list [4][1] = 1
    nested_list [4][5] = 1
    # [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
    try:
        for i in range(len(nested_list), 0, -1):
            for j in range(len(nested_list[0])):
                if nested_list[i-1][j] == 0:
                        count += 1
                        if count == amount:
                            return (i, j-amount+2)
                        else:
                            count = 0
    except:
        return "not possible to find in one floor"
```

Any effective hints or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please edit your code and put there `nested_list` too (so the code can run)?

Comment: What's wrong with your try?

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm not getting the desired output. Sometimes the values of "starting from room no" coming are negative.

Comment: I don't think that using `try: except:` makes sense here. what exception are you expecting?

Comment: @NabilDaoud I assumed that if the index is going out of range, it will raise indexerror.

Comment: Index won't go out of range, you handled that by basing the arguments passed to range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the desired output with slightly different indentation:

```
nested_list_temp = [[0]*7]*5
nested_list = [list(i) for i in nested_list_temp]
nested_list [1][5] = 1
nested_list [2][3] = 1
nested_list [2][4] = 1
nested_list [3][2] = 1
nested_list [4][1] = 1
nested_list [4][5] = 1

def adjacent_rooms(amount):
    for i in range(len(nested_list), 0, -1):
        count = 0
        for j in range(len(nested_list[0])):
            if nested_list[i-1][j] == 0:
                count += 1
                if count == amount:
                    return (i, j-amount+2)
            else:
                count = 0
    return "not possible to find in one floor"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was the position of the last "return" (of that string) that I thought should go as failure, but it's the ultimate return value.

Answer (score 2):

**Use narrow `try-except` conditions**. The first problem is your all-encompassing
error catching, which hides a wide variety of failures -- including outright
code bugs, such as your failure to initialize `count`. So the first thing I did
was to delete the `try-except`. You don't really need it here. And even if you
did, you want to declare one or more specific exceptions in the `except` clause
rather than leaving it wide open.

**Work within Python's list indexing as long as possible**. It seems that you
want to return human-oriented floor/room numbers (starting at 1) rather
than computer-oriented numbers (starting at 0). That's fine. But defer the
computer-to-human conversion as long as possible. Within the guts of your
algorithmic code, work with Python's indexing scheme. In your case, your
code straddles both, sometimes using 1-based indexing, sometimes 0-based.
That's confusing.

**You are resetting `count` too often.** It should be set whenever the room
is full. But you are resetting it whenever `count` does not equal `amount`.
As a result, `count` is almost always being reset to zero.

**You are also resetting `count` too infrequently.** It must be reset at the
start of each new floor.

If we make those changes, we get this:

```
def adjacent_rooms(nested_list, amount):
    for i in range(len(nested_list), 0, -1):
        count = 0
        for j in range(len(nested_list[0])):
            if nested_list[i-1][j] == 0:
                count += 1
                if count == amount:
                    return (i, j-amount+2)
            else:
                count = 0
```

**Python lists are directly iterable**. As a result, you almost never
need to mess around with list indexes and `range()` to process list data.
Just iterate directly to access the values. And for those cases where
you need both the value and the index, use `enumerate()`.

**Use more declarative variable names**. Names like `hotel`, `floor`, and
`room` help the reader understand your code.

**Return data, not textual messages**. If a function returns a tuple of
integers upon success, what should it do upon non-serious failure? It depends
on the context, but you can either raise an exception or return some variant of
`None`. In your case, I would probably opt for a parallel tuple: `(None, None)`. This allows the caller to interact with the function in a fairly
natural way and then simply check either value for `None`. But returning a
textual message is quite unhelpful for callers: the returned data bundle has a
different outer structure (string vs tuple), and it has a different inner data
type (string vs int).

**Don't depend on global variables**. Pass the hotel data into
the function, as a proper argument.

If we make those changes, we get something like this:

```
def adjacent_rooms(hotel, wanted):
    for fi, floor in enumerate(hotel):
        n = 0
        for ri, room in enumerate(floor):
            if room == 0:
                n += 1
                if n == wanted:
                    return (fi + 1, ri - n + 2)
            else:
                n = 0
    return (None, None)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty much new in python. I'll remember your suggestions.

Comment: That is an excellent principle-based answer the improves the code incrementally.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
def adjacent_rooms(nested_list, amount):
    to_search = "0" * amount
    for floor in range(len(nested_list) - 1, -1, -1):
        try:
            idx = "".join(map(str, nested_list[floor])).index(to_search)
            return "floor no: {}, start from room no: {}".format(
                floor + 1, idx + 1
            )
        except ValueError:
            continue

    return "not possible to find in one floor"


nested_list = [[0 for _ in range(7)] for _ in range(5)]
nested_list[1][5] = 1
nested_list[2][3] = 1
nested_list[2][4] = 1
nested_list[3][2] = 1
nested_list[4][1] = 1
nested_list[4][5] = 1

for f in range(1, 10):
    print("f={}, result: {}".format(f, adjacent_rooms(nested_list, f)))
```

Prints:

```
f=1, result: floor no: 5, start from room no: 1
f=2, result: floor no: 5, start from room no: 3
f=3, result: floor no: 5, start from room no: 3
f=4, result: floor no: 4, start from room no: 4
f=5, result: floor no: 2, start from room no: 1
f=6, result: floor no: 1, start from room no: 1
f=7, result: floor no: 1, start from room no: 1
f=8, result: not possible to find in one floor
f=9, result: not possible to find in one floor
```

Comment: Thanks! Although the nested list wasn't as argument, hopefully I can handle. Learnt another application of "continue".